# Native library for TensorFlow java on windows

Tags: java, windows, tensorflow

Now that there is experimental support for Java on TensorFlow, I wanted to get started on Windows, following the steps in the readme

**https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/README.md**

I got the expected error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
```

The Python version is running fine, but that is not Java....

The readme points to native libraries for Mac and Linux, can someone confirm that I just have to wait a bit ?

Comment: The native libraries for Windows haven't been built/released, but have you tried the "Building from source" instructions in the README for creating the native library?

Comment: @ash No I started in "lazy" mode... to be continued

Comment: @ash hey, how to build from source in windows? I couldnt find any detailed instructions for it.

Comment: It is a bit involved, but you can follow [the shell script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/windows/libtensorflow_cpu.sh) that will be used to build the release binary for Windows in the next TensorFlow release (version 1.1).

You can follow release progress in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7877

Answer (score 2):

This works for me when I added the native i.e tensorflow_jni.dll on PC or libtensorflow_jni.dylib on Mac(this should be the same for Linux distributions, not tested though) to my project root folder as seen here [Adding Tensorflow to Java Project Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711054/adding-tensorflow-to-java-project-netbeans). Though I'm using Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but nevertheless I would like to warn you in advance.

The support for Tensor Flow is very experimental indeed.
(February 2018) - You are still very dependent of Python.

Most importantly, there is **no support for training networks in Java**.
You can only apply/run networks.

(Not even to mention the very limited number of available classes).
If you do want to go ahead, I recommend you to **take a look on Github** because there are some **utility classes** there which will be more than useful for you. At least that will give you more comfort.

Comment: As an alternative to TensorFlow in java, I'm really enjoying Neuroph right now.

Answer (score 1):

*java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: tensorflow_native_libraries tensorflow_jni.dll: Can't find depedent libraries* happens because of some Missing DLLs in Windows which tensorflow_jni.dll cannot seem to find.

- Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Resdistributable on Windows
  machine [Download here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)
- Try to close existing command prompts and then re-run the Tensorflow
  Java Program.

See below link for more details
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14456

Answer (score -2):

Add the below code in Maven pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
     <artifactId>tensorflow</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

You can find the installation of tensorflow for java detailed description in below link
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java